# Назначить комбинацию клавиш для "Заменить следующий" и "Заменить все" в Replace menu (Ctrl + H) в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Я хотел заменить название переменной в следующих 5 строках кода. Нажал комбинацию клавиш Ctrl + H и открылось меню для замены названия переменной. Там есть клавиши: Заменить следующий (Alt + R) и заменить все (Alt + A)

НО. Эти комбинации клавиш (Alt + A и Alt + R) просто не работают. Вообще никак. Если нажимать на эти кнопки, то всё хорошо. Но вот если с помощью комбинации клавиш, то никак. Пробовал искать в настройка Visual Studio - не нашёл. В инете тоже не смог найти.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь:)